I can't see the link to the ranks below the points in my profile anymore
Before, in my profile below the points the user has in this SE, I could see a link to the rankings. This still happens in other SEs but it doesnt happen here anymore. Is it a bug? How can I see SciFi SE rankings?

Possibly due to this recent update - Stack Exchange reputation leagues will soon list only the top 400 users

@fez doesnt it say there that I should see something anyway, like how far I am from the top 400?

I'm not entirely sure, but I think it's there in the reputation block in your profile's activity page - https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/17551/pablo?tab=topactivity - I can see your rank for SciFi, but not for SO

You can view the rankings manually by visiting the "all" pages in the users tab

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?page=13&tab=reputation&filter=all

You're on 5651 rep which puts you at the bottom of page 13. There are 36 users per page which mean that you're at position #502.

For the record, I've not checked my own position for a while, but I believe I might be slightly higher up ;-)

Valorum: "I don't have a problem! I can stop using this site whenever I want!" :P

@AndresF. - If you've got time to complain about being addicted to rep, that means you've got time to go through the unanswered question stack and make yourself useful.

Somebody's grouchy today ;) I didn't complain, and I try to answer every question I can, but regrettably most low-hanging fruit seems to have been answered already, and I have a day job too. These days I mostly fix poorly written question titles. I have too long a way to reach your rep!

@AndresF. - When I joined, DVK was in an 'unassailable' lead. Nobody is uncatchable.

It helped that DVK "quit" the site for a long while :P In any case, don't be mad, it was just a joke. I have other hobbies that take more of my time, scifi.se is just to kill time for me. You'll notice I'm seldom in chat: I simply cannot waste time being constantly online here or "hanging out". So my contributions are smaller, drive-by edits and such. Priorities! (edit: I completely abandoned programmers.se or whatever it is called now because that site is an entire waste of time. At least scifi.se is fun!)

@AndresF. - "I have a day job too" - I have identified the problem. If you resolve that, you will have more time to answer questions :-)

Agreed! I tried becoming rich and also selling my daughter to the black market (gaining both more spare time AND money -- win-win) but somehow I couldn't make it work. Also my wife informed me selling children is illegal :(
